# Transform <img/> into Banner

Tags: html, css

I would like to transform an  element into a banner which fill a div without distortion.

As u can see on my picture, I want that picture 1 become like picture 2 using a zoom on the original picture as I did for picture 3.

I tried so much things with css, the fact is picture 3 is from a background-url so it was easy, but picture 1 is a  div (forced because src comes from phpFunction).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to achieve it is same as in pic 3 and just echoing out:

```
<div style="...">
```

or you can remove padding for that div and insert another div to store content and use padding on it